# Consecutive numbers with prime factorizations with at least one exponent greater than or equal to 1000

Tags: number-theory

Let a positive integer n be called a super exponential number if its prime factorization contains at least one prime to a power of 1000 or larger. Prove or disprove the following statement: There exist two consecutive super exponential numbers.

Comment: Hint: $2^{1000}$ and $3^{1000}$ are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

$(2^{1000}+1)^{1000}-1$ has a factor $(2^{1000}+1)-1=2^{1000}$, and then comes $(2^{1000}+1)^{1000}$.